# Receiving a reference error when using ko.applybinding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have the following code,

```
<div class="title">
    <a href="#" data-bind="text: MovieName, attr: { href: DetailsUrl }"></a>
</div>
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "text: function (){return MovieName }"
Message: MovieName is not defined
```

I have gone through debug several times and I see my data, and I see the name data.MovieName being loaded. So, what am I missing?

If anyone can help I would truly appreciate it.

Comment: Can you post the js part that causes trouble.

Comment: A fiddle demonstating the problem would also help us and yourself to visualize the problem. You get that error because `MovieName` does not exist in that context. Can you verify that the root context is your `data` and that it indeed has the `MovieName` property?

Comment: figured it out ... as I said I didn't write this so I copied it from a working program, but what I didn't realize was that there was on foreach around my <div for MovieName, Rating or showtimes all of that data had to have been defined somewhere...then I saw commented out foreach {data:movies} and I put that around my divs for the markup and that performed the bindings correctly. Thanks for all of your help

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer to my question. I was missing the `<div databind="foreach {data:movies}" >` around my bindings